# Magento Redirect Loop

Tags: magento-1.9

I have a dev site on magento 1.9.4.2 . Now I am trying to redirect my web site to my domain (the server is the same)

I have changed the

1. web/unsecure/base_url
2. web/secure/base_url
3. and web/url/redirect_to_base to 0.

I have also cleared

1. var/cache
2. and var/session.
3. system/tmp/magento/cache

But I am still getting a redirect loop issue.

can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide us with your .htaccess file in your Magento directory? This could be because your .htaccess redirects all your urls to `http://www.yourdomain.com` but your Magento installation is trying to redirect to `www.yourdomain.com` or `yourdomain.com` (yes, there's a difference). You can check this by adding / removing `http://www.` and `www.` from your web/unsecure/base_url and web/secure/base_url.

Comment: on the default .htaccess i found that www.yourdomain.com and i switched to my new an still nothing...for a test i deleted my .htaccess and still nothing...dont know what to do more

Comment: and in my web/unsecure/base_url i have tryied with www.domain.com/ and www.domain.com

Comment: after changing back to my .htaccess i changed all `www.yourdomain.com` to my domain and 2 things happen..when i go with my domain my page enter in a infinite loop beteewn domain and the ip/path, and when i try to access with ip/path it redirects to `www.yourdomain.com`, but i checked and my .htaccess does not have more references to it

Comment: If you try to save the following code as `cleancache.php` in your Magento directory: [link](http://pastebin.com/QEGjZsWr) and then delete/rename your `.htaccess`. Then run www.yourdomain.com/cleancache.php what do you see?

Also make sure that you set the same url http://www.yourdomain.com for every store(view) and not just the default in Magento.

Comment: Start Cleaning all caches at ... 2016-08-02 19:53:38 Cleaning data cache... Removing config ... [OK] Removing layout ... [OK] Removing block_html ... [OK] Removing translate ... [OK] Removing collections ... [OK] Removing eav ... [OK] Removing config_api ... [OK] Removing config_api2 ... [OK] Cleaning stored cache... [OK] Cleaning merged JS/CSS...[OK] Cleaning image cache... [OK]

Comment: and it keeps looping

Comment: and another thing when i go to `mydomain.com` the site enters in a loop beteewn domain and ip/path but i i try `mydomain.com/index.php` its says page not found